# Calling jQuery Get after Post

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am trying to call a jQuery GET request on the successful completion of a POST request. The functions work and the data is being fed through from the GET request, however, it is responding before the POST.

```
function getCartCount() {
    var d = new Date().getTime();
    $.get("/ajax/countCart.php", { "rand": d }, function(res) {
        $("#view-cart").text(res);          
        alert(res);
    });
}

$(".products form img").click(function() {
    $.post("/ajax/addToCart.php", $(this).parent("form").serialize())
    .done(function(data) {
        alert(data);
    })
    .always(getCartCount());
});
```

The above code produces an alert box from the GET request first then an alert box from the POST which is not ideal as the value from the GET is dependent on the POST being completed first.

Please see http://www.cccomforts.co.uk/small-furries for the output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because you are not waiting for POST request to complete successfully. Do this -

```
$(".products form img").click(function() {
    $.post("/ajax/addToCart.php", $(this).parent("form").serialize())
    .done(function(data) {
        alert(data);
        getCartCount();
    })
});
```

Comment: Incorrect answer - the correct answer is the one from @Quentin. The OP intends to call `getCartCount()` in the always callback, he just called the function instead of passing the function reference as an argument to `always()`. That being said, it probably only makes sense to put `getCartCount()` in the done callback, because it doesn't appear to make sense to call that method when your original post failed.

Comment: OP says, he wants to call GET on 'successful' completion of POST. So, the best way to do that will be to keep GET call inside .done. That is why the answer.

Comment: Thanks @Sam your fix worked, such a simple thing to overlook as well!

Answer (score 2):

```
.always(getCartCount());
                    ^^
```

You are calling the function immediately and passing the return value to `always`.

Remove the `()` to pass the function itself.

```
.always(getCartCount);
```